# Return a dynamic array

Tags: c++

So I want to make an executable with three functions:

This would be an example:

```
float vec(int opt, int t)
{
int i;
float * v = new float[t];
// Do stuff with v
return * v;
}
}
```

It gets arguments *opt* and *t*  from **main**. Then main needs to get *v* back to use it in another function.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead. You're returning a single float there.

Comment: Read a good [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn the basics of the language.

Comment: What is the relevance of the three functions?

Comment: Corrected, I am now using std::vector.

Comment: Rolled back to your original post. You're not supposed to ask a question and then swap it for a different one.

Comment: Okay, let's consider this solved.

Answer (score 2):

The return type of `vec` should be `float *`, and your return statement should be `return v`. Dereferencing `v` with `*` just gives you the first element of the array.

I'll note that this kind of design is bad style. It relies on the caller to free the dynamically allocated array. It would be better to have the caller create an array and pass it by reference to `vec`, or have `vec` return a different container statically. @Mat suggested `std::vector`; that's probably a good choice.

You also have an extra `}` at the end of your function. Get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your signature says that the function returns a single `float`, not an array of floats.  To answer your question directly...

```
float *vec(int t)
{
    float * v = new float[t];
    // Do stuff with v
    return v;
}
```

> What is the best way to do this?

Well that's a different question entirely.  The "best" way would be to return a `std::vector<float>` and avoid manual memory management altogether.